# Elastic Beanstalk deployment stuck on updating config settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been testing my continuous deployment setup, trying to get to a minimal set of IAM permissions that will allow my CI IAM group to deploy to my "staging" Elastic Beanstalk environment.

On my latest test, my deployment got stuck. The last event in the console is:

```
Updating environment staging's configuration settings.
```

Luckily, the deployment will time out after 30 minutes, so the environment can be deployed to again.

It seems to be a permissions issue, because if I grant `s3:*` on all resources, the deployment works. It seems that when calling [UpdateEnvironment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateEnvironment.html), Elastic Beanstalk does something to S3, but I can't figure out what.

I have tried the following policy to give EB full access to its resource bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-REGION-ACCOUNT/resources/_runtime/_embedded_extensions/APP",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-REGION-ACCOUNT/resources/_runtime/_embedded_extensions/APP/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-REGION-ACCOUNT/resources/environments/ENV_ID",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-REGION-ACCOUNT/resources/environments/ENV_ID/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Where `REGION`, `ACCOUNT`, `APP`, and `ENV_ID` are my AWS region, account number, application name, and environment ID, respectively.

Does anyone have a clue which S3 action and resource EB is trying to access?

Answer (score 8):

[Shared this on your blog already](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915120358/https://nudaygames.squarespace.com/blog/2014/5/26/deploying-to-elastic-beanstalk-from-your-continuous-integration-system), but this might have a broader audience so here it goes:

Following up on this, the ElastiBeanstalk team has provided me with the following answer regarding the S3 permissions:

> "[...]Seeing the requirement below, would a slightly locked down version work? I've attached a policy to this case which will grant s3:GetObject on buckets starting with elasticbeanstalk. This is essentially to allow access to all elasticbeanstalk buckets, including the ones that we own. The only thing you'll need to do with our bucket is a GetObject, so this should be enough to do everything you need."

So it seems like ElasticBeanstalk is accessing buckets out of anyone's realm in order to work properly (which is kind of bad, but that's just the way it is).

Coming from this, the following policy will be sufficient for getting things to work with S3:

```
{
  "Action": "s3:*",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-<region>-<account_id>",
    "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-<region>-<account_id>/",
    "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-<region>-<account_id>/*"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow"
},
{
  "Action": "s3:GetObject",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk*",
  "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

Obviously, you need to wrap this into a proper policy statement that IAM understands. All your previous assumptions about IAM policies have proven right though so I'm guessing this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: This is outstanding. After hours of trial and error, this policy is the first one that let me do a locked down deploy from Codeship. Thankyou! Why can't AWS document this stuff? There is nothing in their API doc about "secret roles we're gonna need". And the Managed Policy they propose is basically "open access to everything"... what's with that?

Comment: @qu1j0t3 I concur. I'm really surprised that managed policies are simply "give this user/role/group access to do everything on eb, sqs, rds, etc"